# How to make a control label display traditional form notation

Tags: manipulate, traditional-form

How do you make a control label display notation in tradition form?  I would like the label to display the function "f(x)= (1/2)x+1" but in traditional form.  How could I modify this code so it works?  I realize I am using a string, so I would need to change that but don't know what to do.

```
Manipulate[Plot[If[f, .5 x + 1], {x, -3, 6},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-1, 5}},
  Ticks -> {Range[-3, 6], Range[-1, 5]},
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.03], 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.03]],

 {{f, False, "f(x)=(1/2)x+1"}, {True, False}}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[If[f, .5 x + 1], {x, -3, 6},
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-1, 5}},
  Ticks -> {Range[-3, 6], Range[-1, 5]},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.03],
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.03]],
 {{f, False, TraditionalForm[Style["f", Italic][x] == (1/2) x + 1]}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I fiddled a little and this works too.  I went into the Option Inspector and changed the "InputInline" Cell option to Traditional Form.  The code below works so long as I use an Inlinecell inside the quotation marks.  One of the positives of doing it this way is that Mathematica doesn't simplify the (1/2)x to x/2.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[If[f, .5 x + 1], {x, -3, 6}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-1, 5}}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[-3, 6], Range[-1, 5]}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.03], 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.03]], {{f, False, "f(x) = 1/2x+1"}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]